# Why is the signal not emitted in this code?

Tags: java, godot

I created a Pollfish Plugin for Godot.But the signal is not emitted there.

Showing the Pollfish Offerwall. But even if the Pollfish Offerwall is closed, the signal here will not be emitted.

And there is nothing wrong with my Gdscript code. I previously created a Unity ads plugin but it worked fine. This just doesn't work. Someone help with this. thank you.

```
public class PollfishPlugin extends GodotPlugin implements PollfishClosedListener{

    private Activity activity;
    private FrameLayout layout = null;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onMainCreate(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = getActivity();
        layout = new FrameLayout(activity);
        return layout;
    }

    public PollfishPlugin(Godot godot) {
        super(godot);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getPluginName() {
        return "PollfishPlugin";
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Set<SignalInfo> getPluginSignals() {
        Set<SignalInfo> signals = new ArraySet<>();
        signals.add(new SignalInfo("onPollfishClosed"));
        return signals;
    }

    @UsedByGodot
    public void init(){
        initPollfish();
    }

    private void initPollfish(){

        Params params = new Params.Builder("180b54b9-1353-4656-b5f2-e1d0aad2fa61")
                .rewardMode(true)
                .offerwallMode(true)
                .build();

        Pollfish.initWith(activity, params);
    }

    @UsedByGodot
    public void showPollfish(){
        Pollfish.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPollfishClosed() {
        emitSignal("onPollfishClosed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of Waiting for Godot, you're Polling for Godot ;)